# Laravel 5: Model->fill() ignores $fillable property in unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I have a user controller with the following validation rules:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ...
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'confirmed|max:32|min:8|required',
        'roles' => 'exists:roles,id|required',
    ]);

    $user = new User();
    $user->fill($request->all());
   ...
}
```

My User.php model defines the fillable properties as:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];
```

To pass the `confirmed` validation, I have to send both `password` and `password_confirmation` fields in the POST request.

During development everything works fine, but in unit tests I'm getting a database error. It tries to insert data into a password_confirmation column. It's like it ignores the `$fillable` array.

I know about the "laravel losts event handlers between tests" bug/issue (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1181). So I think that maybe I'm missing to call some model function aside from `Model::boot()` (I'm calling `User::boot()` in the test's `setUp()` function).

Thanks,

### Edit

Reading the Model.php source, I've found that someone is calling `Model::unguard()` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2180 after the setUp() function and before the test. If I call `User::reguard()` at the beggining of the test it passes, but (I don't know why), the unguard() and reguard() functions get called multiple times and the test gets really slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem: the base seeder in v5.0.x only called Model::unguard() (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.0.22/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php#L15) while v5.1.x was updated and added a call to Model::reguard() (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.1.0/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php#L19) (I was using v5.0.22).

Answer (score 1):

Fillable only applies to MassAssignment. When you're creating a new instance, like what you're doing above, you're not triggering the mass assignment event.

You could do something like this:
If you're creating the user anyway, you might as well do:

```
$user = User::create($request->all);
```

If you just want to instantiate the user, without persisting the data, you could do something like this:

```
$user = new User($request);
```

Comment: Calling `Model::create($attributes)` ends up calling the `Model::fill()` function, [see Eloquent/Model.php source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L270). The problem is that it respects the $fillable array in dev but not in tests.