# Laravel units tests override guarded Model properties

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, eloquent

I have a set of unit tests in Laravel 5.3 for testing API Controllers. When we run the tests, the controllers call `Model::fill($request->all())`. In normal execution of the code, this works just fine. But in our tests, it seems to ignore guarded properties. For instance, in our UserController test, it puts through `password_confirmation = "password"` as part of the UPDATE statement, even though the Model itself explicitly guards against it. Here is an example of our code:

```
// the test
public function testUpdate()
{
    $user     = factory(User::class)->create();
    $password = '^MyIns3curePassw0rd';

    $this->json('POST', 'api/users/'.$user->id.'/update', [
        'name'                  => $user->name,
        'email'                 => $user->email,
        'password'              => $password,
        'password_confirmation' => $password,
    ])->assertResponseOk();

    $this->seeJson([ 'name' => $user->name ]);
}

// the controller
public function update(UserRequest $request, $userId)
{
    $user = null;

    $this->db->transaction(function () use ($userId, &$user) {
        $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
        $user->fill($this->request->all());
        $user->save();
    });

    return response()->json($user);
}

// the model
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{

    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, Notifiable;


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['password_confirmation'];
}
```

Is there a reason this is happening and can I fix it? I have found some similar questions, notably [Laravel 5: Model->fill() ignores $fillable property in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940847/laravel-5-model-fill-ignores-fillable-property-in-unit-tests), but everything appears to be for pre-5.1 releases and we are running 5.3.x (I have tested on both 5.3.9, which is what we were on previously, and 5.3.30)

Comment: What traits are you using in your test class?

Comment: @Paras `DatabaseTransactions` and `WithoutMiddleware`. We have a base test case that bootstraps some login logic, but nothing unguards anything or goes around the guard logic in any way. Additionally, it is happening in 15 other cases for different models and controllers. I can post that base test if necessary